# Pandas dataframe condition on datetime at other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-analysis

My dataframe is shown as follows:

```
  User     Date       Unit   
1  A     2000-10-31    1      
2  A     2001-10-31    2           
3  A     2002-10-31    1        
4  A     2003-10-31    2        
5  B     2000-07-31    1        
6  B     2000-08-31    2       
7  B     2001-07-31    1       
8  B     2002-06-30    1        
9  B     2002-07-31    1
10 B     2002-08-31    1
```

I want to make the following judgement:
(1) For the 'User' with 'Unit' in the same month in the past consecutive two years. The data should be classified as 'Routine' with a dummy variable 1.
(2) Otherwise, the data should be classified as 0 in the 'Routine' column.
(3) For the data do not have two past consecutive years. The 'Routine' column should show NaN.

My desired output is:

```
  User     Date       Unit   Routine
1  A     2000-10-31    1       NaN
2  A     2001-10-31    2       NaN        
3  A     2002-10-31    1        1
4  A     2003-10-31    2        1
5  B     2000-07-31    1       NaN 
6  B     2000-08-31    2       NaN
7  B     2001-07-31    1       NaN
8  B     2002-06-30    1        0
9  B     2002-07-31    1        1
10 B     2002-08-31    1        0
```

The code of the dataframe is shown as follows:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'User':list('AAAABBBBBB'),
             'Date':['2000-10-31','2001-10-31','2002-10-31','2003-10-31','2000-07-31',
                     '2000-08-31','2001-07-31','2002-06-30','2002-07-31','2002-08-31'],
            'Unit':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1]})
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

I want to use groupby function since there are many users in the dataframe. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'User': list('AAAABBBBBB'),
            'Date': [
                '2000-10-31', '2001-10-31', '2002-10-31', '2003-10-31',
                '2000-07-31', '2000-08-31', '2001-07-31', '2002-06-30',
                '2002-07-31', '2002-08-31'],
            'Unit': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])


def routine(user, cdate, unit):
    result = np.nan

    two_years = [cdate.year - 1, cdate.year - 2]
    mask = df.User == user
    mask = mask & df.Date.dt.year.isin(two_years)
    sdf = df[mask]

    years = sdf.Date.dt.year.to_list()
    got_years = all([y in years for y in two_years])
    result = 0 if (sdf.shape[0] > 0) & got_years else result

    mask2 = (sdf.Date.dt.month == cdate.month) & (sdf.Unit == unit)
    sdf = sdf[mask2]
    result = 1 if (sdf.shape[0] > 0) & got_years else result
    return result


df['Routine'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: routine(row['User'], row['Date'], row['Unit']), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  User       Date  Unit  Routine
0    A 2000-10-31     1      NaN
1    A 2001-10-31     2      NaN
2    A 2002-10-31     1      1.0
3    A 2003-10-31     2      1.0
4    B 2000-07-31     1      NaN
5    B 2000-08-31     2      NaN
6    B 2001-07-31     1      NaN
7    B 2002-06-30     1      0.0
8    B 2002-07-31     1      1.0
9    B 2002-08-31     1      0.0
```